# category on iphone 4s not being called

Tags: ios

I have been using the [CCBottomRefreshControl](https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl) in an iOS app for quite some time without any problem. However I am now running into a crash which only appears to occur on iPhone 4s (both a real device running 7.1 and the 4s simulator running 7.1 or 8.1). CCBottomRefreshControl is implemented as a category of UIScrollView, when I set bottomRefreshControl below

```
#import <CCBottomRefreshControl/UIScrollView+BottomRefreshControl.h>

...

UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.tableView.bottomRefreshControl = refreshControl;

- (void)refresh {
    // Do refresh stuff here
}
```

I get a `-[UITableView setBottomRefreshControl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x172a8800` error. The method `setBottomRefreshControl` is in the `UIScrollView` (`BottomRefreshControl`) category. This is 100% consistent. It works fine on all other devices.

Comment: The variable `bottomRefreshControl` you're assigning to `self.tableView.bottomRefreshControl` doesn't seem to exist, is it a typo?

Comment: I don't have any context for this particular library, but in terms of why it might fail only on that "device", could there be an issue in the 32-bit version of the linking or loading of the category that doesn't exist in the 64-bit build? (Does this fail on all 32-bit devices and succeed on 64 bit ones?)

Comment: @DavidJirman yes - you're quite right that is a typo (just in the question, it does read self.tableView.bottomRefreshControl = refreshControl in the code). I've edited the question to reflect that

Comment: @BenZotto interesting. will check that out further